# Private service object methods (Ruby + Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `PaymentManager` service:

```
/payment_manager/
  - online_payment_creator.rb
  - manual_payment_creator.rb
  - payment_splitter.rb
```

Code for 3 services:

```
module PaymentManager
  class ManualPaymentCreator < ApplicationService
    def call
      # do stuff in transaction
      PaymentSplitter.call(a, b, c)
    end
  end
end

module PaymentManager
  class OnlinePaymentCreator < ApplicationService
    # do stuff in transaction
    PaymentSplitter.call(a2, b2, c2)
  end
end

module PaymentManager
  class PaymentSplitter < ApplicationService
    def call(x, y, z)
      # do very dangerous stuff
    end
  end
end
```

So, the `PaymentSplitter` essentially splits a payment across multiple invoices, and must be done **only** inside either of the other 2 services, but should never be called on its own (from a controller or in the console, etc).

I normally would make a `private` method inside `ManualPaymentCreator` but because it's needed in BOTH services, I don't know how to do that, as I can't use a simple private instance method without duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for inheritance and protected methods

```
class Foo < ApplicationService
  def public_method
  end

  protected
    #everything after here is private to this class and its descendants
    def some_method_to_be_shared_with_descendants
      #I am only accessible from this class and from descendants of this class

      ...
    end

  private
    #Everything after here is private to this class only

    def some_private_methods_that_are_only_accessible_from_this_class
    end
    ...
end
```

Then descendant classes like so

```
class Bar < Foo
  def do_something
    # can access protected methods from Foo class here as native methods
    some_res = some_method_to_be_shared_here
    # do something with some_res
  end
end
```

So you should descend your other 2 classes from PaymentSplitter and set the shared methods as protected

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for the naming scheme based on my actual class names? It's a bit confusing because that would mean that `OnlinePaymentCreator < PaymentSplitter` and that seems bizarre... unless im misunderstanding (a `PaymentSplitter` has a specific purpose). Plus there may be multiple other things I want to hide as well.

Comment: @Tallboy It seems fine to have both manual and online payment creator descend from a class called payment_creator rather than PaymentSplitter if that helps although I see no reason to not use PaymentSplitter as the name of the parent

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a private class contained in a module might work better, eg.

```
module PaymentSplitting
  def self.included(klass)
    raise 'Error' unless klass.in?([ManualPaymentCreator, OnlinePaymentCreator])
  end

  class PaymentSplitter
  end
  private_constant :PaymentSplitter
end
```

This should allow you to freely reference `PaymentSplitter` in any class which includes `PaymentSplitting`, and you can only include `PaymentSplitting` in `ManualPaymentCreator` or `OnlinePaymentCreator`. Referencing `PaymentSplitting::PaymentSplitter` will throw a `NameError: private constant` exception.